# For rings: containment and isomorphism does not imply equality.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

So I have been asked to find two commutative unital rings $A$ and $B$ such that

$B\subseteq A$  and $A\cong B$ but $A\neq B.$

I give my solution below.

I would be very grateful if someone could tell me whether I'm right and, if not, give me a hint.

Consider the rings $A=\mathbb{Z}[\pi] \subset \mathbb{C}$ and $B=\mathbb{Z}[\pi^2] \subset \mathbb{C}.$ Clearly $B\subseteq A.$

By the fact that $\pi$ is transcendental, we have that

$A\cong \mathbb{Z}[X] \cong B$

but also that $\pi \notin B$ and so

$A\neq B.$

Comment: This is correct, but you don't need to bring $\pi$ into it; this is just a statement about polynomial rings, namely that $k[x]$ strictly contains the isomorphic ring $k[x^2]$ as a subring.